# Using Data Model as Excel 2016 Graph's Source

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a rather specific but an easy question. Couldn't find any related topics among all of those basic guides. Hope someone can help me. Here it goes:

I'm using Excel 2016 and I'm creating a workbook which has no data input other than sql queries and I added these queries only to the data model. As far as pivottables concerned there is no problem. But when I try to add a graph without a pivottable connection excel doesn't list my data models as source. There is only one reference box which is labeled "Chart data range" and I couldn't find how can I reference my data model table as range. Well, I don't even know if I can.

Hope someone can clear this for me before I change my whole structure.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
As far as I know you can't reference data model if you add your graph from excel spreadsheet. But you can add your graph other way around which is from PowerPivot data model UI.